# how to append text down to up in html and python

Tags: python, html

I have an HTML file that puts a line break after logging information (a string).

Instead of putting lines one by one from up - down, I want them the other way around.

For example, from

> (1) 
>   (2) 
>   (3)

I need

> (3) 
>   (2) 
>   (1)

```
try:
    record_cam.strHandler.flush()
    ret +="""
    <p>%s</p>
    """ % cgi.escape( record_cam.strLog.getvalue().replace("\n", "<br>"))
except Exception as a:
    print(str(a))
    pass
```

Comment: I'm afraid no one can make sense of your question the way it's actually written.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I would like to show the text down side up not up side down

Comment: You wrote that "instead of 1,2,3" you need "1, 2, 3" - doesn't really makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, assuming you mistyped "I need 1,2,3" instead of "I need 3,2,1", the solution is simple: split your text on newlines, reverse the list, join using "
":

```
logs = record_cam.strLog.getvalue()
logs = "<br>".join(reversed(logs.splitlines()))
ret +="""
        <p>%s</p>
    """ % logs
```

As a side note, cgi is a bit of dinosaur... We now have wsgi and quite a few frameworks on top of it.

EDIT: removed the (copy-pasted) call to `cgi.escape()` - I really doubt you want to escape markup here...

Comment: I tried your code, but <br> is printed and all the logs are in the same line (just one line )

Comment: The problem is actually in your own code - did you read the documentation for `cgi.escape()` ?